# How to verify username and password where the data is stored in data-base which is not local using cookies?

Tags: javascript, database, cookies, session-cookies

I am working on a website where I have obtained the username and password from the web page using javaScript. How to verify it with data-base using cookies?

Comment: you should send it to your backend server, which then verifies using the database ..

Comment: the usual way ...  read the database, compare the values

Comment: the passwords SHOULD NOT be stored as cleartext in the database

Comment: Never store passwords in cookies if you intend to do it